# Entire program not working due to one logical error

Tags: arm, embedded, lpc

I am using NEX Robotics board for LPC2148. I find very strange problem with below lines of code.

```
//Prototypes
void diaplayInRow1WithPosition(unsigned char* data, unsigned char position);
void diaplayInRow2WithPosition(unsigned char* data, unsigned char position);
unsigned char convertHigherNibbleToASCIIValue(unsigned char data);
unsigned char convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue(unsigned char data);
int main (void)
{
    unsigned char temp2;
    unsigned int PLLStatus;
    initializeAll();
    PLLStatus = PLL0STAT; 
    temp2 =   convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue(PLLStatus);
    diaplayInRow1WithPosition(&temp2,15);
    temp2 = convertHigherNibbleToASCIIValue(PLLStatus);
    diaplayInRow1WithPosition(&temp2,14);
    temp2 = PLLStatus>>8;
    temp2 =   convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue(PLLStatus);
    diaplayInRow1WithPosition(&temp2,13);
    return(0);
}
```

When this code is executed, I see a blank display. I noticed that the problem is with last convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue function call. It should have been:

```
temp2 =   convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue(temp2 );
```

But because of this one line error, why entire display is blank? Only last function diaplayInRow1WithPosition should have given trouble right? 
Even after changing with above line, I am getting blank display. So I replaced that line containing last convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue as

```
temp2 =   convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue(PLLStatus>>8);
```

And finally I got correct display.

Unable to digest the problem. Anyone can help? Main answer I need is if at all there is a problem in one line, why previous lines are not getting executed correctly? I am using Keil compiler and any compiler dependencies? There is no compilation error.
If there is a problem with types etc, will entire program get corrupted?

Comment: This is hard for anyone else to analyze without the code of those functions.  Something you might do is compare the listing files or disassembly of the two versions and see what has changed.  Or you can run under a breakpoint debugger, or add monitoring output such as a serial port or changing the state of GPIOs at points in your program which you can monitor with a scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found that the issue is with Keil compiler. If I add one additional dummy line (could be any assignment statement), code works!!! Somewhere some optimization is happening, but unable to make out where. Anyway I have work around now. Add one dummy if does not work and remove again if not needed!!!

Answer (score 0):

More likely than your *"entire program not working"* is that either:

- the display data is buffered and the program crashes before the buffered data reaches the display,
- or simply that the value of `PLLStatus` is not displayable and has the effect of blanking the display or perhaps stops it working correctly altogether - it may not be a printable character, and we are given no information about the display hardware or its API, so the effect of *garbage-in* is undefined.